# Add ionic to existing Angular app ... npm errors

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Following the official Angular "Tour of Heros App and Tutorial", downloaded the [example](https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip) and run 'npm install' ok.

When adding ionic to existing Angular App according to Ionic doc [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cdn):

```
ng add @ionic/angular
```

There are npm errors.  How can add ionic to the very first Angular tutorial demo?  Anyone encountered the same issue?

npm run ng add @ionic/angular

```
> angular.io-example@0.0.0 ng
> ng "add" "@ionic/angular"

Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
CREATE src/theme/variables.css (288 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1438 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (1497 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (6067 bytes)
⠼ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular.io-example@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~0.1100.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.4" from @ionic/angular-toolkit@3.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
npm ERR!   dev @ionic/angular-toolkit@"latest" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /home/xxx/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xxx/.npm/_logs/2021-03-29T07_50_28_511Z-debug.log
```

Versions currently used:
Angular CLI: 11.0.7 /
Node: 14.16.0 /
OS: linux x64 /
Angular: 11.0.9 /
ionic: 6.13.1

Comment: can you run this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps flag?

Comment: @playerone it says unknown option: '--force' or '--legacy-peer-deps'